# Does AWS Kinesis Firehose provides integrity controls during the data transfer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

AWS Kinesis firehose is used to transfer logs from Service Provider AWS cloud account to S3 Bucket in consumer AWS cloud Account. Does AWS provides tamper-proof controls to ensure the integrity of logs received at Consumer AWS cloud Account.

Answer (score 0):

The only AWS service that I am aware of which provides its [own data integrity validation is CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-log-file-custom-validation.html). This makes sense in a way, as CloudTrail log data is kind of a closed loop - internal to AWS only - and so they can provide reasonably trustworthy integrity checks on it.

Firehose does not provide its own integrity validation controls. I assume this is because it can receive external data and store it on AWS. For Firehose, the best you can do is implement [security best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/security-best-practices.html). Similarly for [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/security-best-practices.html).